# How to deploy to Salesforce Custom Object metada using python?

Tags: python, salesforce, suds

It seems I can communicate with Salesforce [Metadata API](http://www.google.by/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=salesforce%20metadata%20api&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CBgQFjAA&url=http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api_meta/index.htm&ei=ZF0NT5j_MIXf4QTs5tyeBg&usg=AFQjCNF9wQ8J5C5OaCFgf2Hr6vrJ4OU7OQ) just using SOAP python client ([suds](https://fedorahosted.org/suds/)?)

Is there any more elegant way? I know about

- [salesforce-python-toolkit](http://code.google.com/p/salesforce-python-toolkit/)
- [salesforce-beatbox](http://code.google.com/p/salesforce-beatbox/)

but I could not find any example or documentation reference..

Any suggestion, reference or example would be appreciated!

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Salesforce does have a REST API but as far as I'm aware at this stage, the metadata operations are limited and also read-only, so using SOAP is the way forward.

The two projects you've linked to appear to be wrappers for the regular salesforce API and the bulk data API, that said, the source is available so maybe you could adapt one? Or wait for Superfell to answer, looks like he wrote the beatbox one!

Comment: I'm not aware of any metadata API specific helpers in python.